# Can we move the data stored in sqlite to MSSQL Server in android?

Tags: android

We have downloaded one application in android which it is storing data in SQLITE Database. We need to connect our application to remote MSSQL Server and save the data in MSSQL Server instead of storing in SQLITE. How to connect our application directly to MSSQL server. Please give us some sample code. We are struggling a lot for this.

Answer (score 0):

There are questions revolving around the same issues.

Have you investigated all the resources in the thread called [Connecting android with MS SQL SERVER 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255984/connecting-android-with-ms-sql-server-2008) ?