# How to connect with sql server to develop android app?

Tags: android, sql, sql-server

I have a task to connect to connect to a SQL Server in the network to develop an android app using C#.NET in Visual Studio 2010.

How do I connect to SQL Server?

Where do I have to write the connection string?

How do I have to call that method?

Comment: Hope http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255984/connecting-android-with-ms-sql-server-2008 helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not access directly to DB, you would need some api to access the database server, I would recommend to use webservices, which will provide an interface between your db and your application.

Answer (score 1):

I think u need a layer to encapsulate sql server to provide operation APIs, such as web service, WCF or Domain Serveice.