# Xamarin for Android with SQL Server 2008

Tags: android, sql-server-2008, xamarin

I want to develop a mobile app using Xamarin for Android.  My clients will be using SQL Server 2008 database.  How can I use Xamarin for Android to access SQL server 2008 database?

I have searched for it but it seems that most Xamarin apps use SQLite database in which files are stored on the device.  This will not work for me as SQL server 2008 is a requirement.

I have found info on buidling Android app with SQL server but those use Java whereas Xamarin will use C#.

Can you please point me to some good tutorials or samples?

I appreciate your guidance.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connecting android with MS SQL SERVER 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255984/connecting-android-with-ms-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should build a Web Service to access the Database,  and the Xamarin application can call the Web Service without any problems.

Here you have an introduction to different Web Services

http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/introduction_to_web_services

Comment: Thank you, Daniel. This really helped. I am able to create WCF service and get the response in JSON. Can you please guide me on how to read this JSON in my Xamarin for android app using C#? I have searched and most of the results use Java.. Thanks again!