# conect to microsoft 2003 database from android

Tags: java, android, sql

i know there are millions of topics on the net about connecting to a external database, but i don't get the clue which ones i have to follow. probably this is because i am an beginner for java and android programming.

my setup:
-microsoft sql server 2005 on a server connected to the internet
-android app i am working on in java (eclipse)

what i want to try first:
-user gives an input number
-i go search this number and return the data from the database do put in on the screen of my android.

i've been reading alot about json and php scripts but i don't know where to start. this database is also used for other windows aplications, there the database is entered by the windows authentication i was told.
is it possible to also use this windows authentication?
anyway, what to do first for me?

thanks in advance

Comment: You first need to understand the architecture to use. You can't directly connect to the database from the mobile device (android, iPhone, whatever) instead connecting through services (mostly RESTful web services). Then, start working on the necessary services and as a last step consume these services from your android application.

Comment: isn't there a standard webservice i can install on my server and then read from/ write to it? writing this kind of service is a complete new thing for me, if not, where i can find a tutorial or so who explains me?

Comment: First thing to know, you can write a Web Service from *any* programming language. Basically, you need a tutorial that explains the steps to accomplish what you need: 1. Define your services. 2. Define the technology to implement the services. 3. Choose the web application server. 4. Write the interfaces to your services. 5. Implement the services (5.1. Separate it in layers to have at least one to connect to the database 5.2. Use the database layer to define the database connection.) 6. Connect your android application to the services.

Comment: i investigated the given info and links a bit and found out that i really have not the experience yet to set such a connection. as a windows program is already comunicating with that database i will ask our software supplier if they use already a webservice like that, maybe i don't need to do al the work that way, anyway, thanks for al the replys

Answer (score 0):

See answers here: [Connecting android with MS SQL SERVER 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255984/connecting-android-with-ms-sql-server-2008)

You should really use a webservice, connecting to the database is not the best practice.

Comment: again i am redirected and redirected and nothing is completely the same to what i want, your links are talking about server 2008, if 1 thing is different i will get in trouble no?

Comment: @keuninkske the only difference is the database engine (which can be easily replaced by the database engine of your preference). I hardly think you could fin a tutorial of *How to do foo and bar that will work for me and only me*