# connect android apps to sql server

Tags: android, database

I am doing android application. I want to connect Microsoft SQL Server 2008 to that application. Is it possible to connect android apps with SQL Server in place of SQLite? If possible Kindly explain with an example?

Comment: This question is already been asked. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255984/connecting-android-with-ms-sql-server-2008